# % of Row Total in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to format my pivot table values as percentages of their row totals (in my data, each quarter). However, when I select Show Values as % of Row Total, it gives each value 100%.

When I try Show Values as % of Parent Row Total, it uses the column as the total and uses the first 4 quarters of 2017 as % total of 2018, not at all what I want to do.

Here is my current pivot table
[image]

Here is how I'm trying to format the same pivot table
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't type all your "types" (or whatever is in the columns), but when I summarize by % of Row Total, it works as expected.

[image: pivot table with % by row]

Is yours set up differently than what I show?

**Update**

If your data points are all separate columns as @jeffreyweir suggests, then you can't summarize them how you want using pivot table features. You'll have to add some columns to your data

[image: table with percent calcs]

Each `Pct` column is a formula:

```
=[@Replacement]/SUM(tbldata[@[Replacement]:[DTK]])
=[@Refund]/SUM(tbldata[@[Replacement]:[DTK]])
=[@Parts]/SUM(tbldata[@[Replacement]:[DTK]])
=[@DTK]/SUM(tbldata[@[Replacement]:[DTK]])
```

Then you can sum those in a pivot table.

[image: pivot table summing calculated fields from a table]

Comment: When I right  click a the first column, I then select "Show values as..." and then select "% of Row Total" I get 100% for every value in that first column. The rest of the row doesn't change

Comment: @George Do you have one field in the Values area like in Dick's screenshot, or do you have multiple fields in there? i.e. do you have separate columns for Replacement, Refund, Parts etc in your source data that you have dragged into the PivotTable Values area one by one?

Comment: Good one @jeffreyweir that's gotta be it. I would think the columns headers would say `Sum of...` but they could have been changed.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it, but seems a bit computationally expensive to me, not to mention still messy in the VALUES pane. Have added an Unpivot answer as another option.